# Update or Insert, Auto increment int in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, increment

I'm trying to auto increment (update) or insert the data in my MySQL database, so everytime the PHP file gets requested it should **update Uses** or **insert the DeviceID  and Uses**, that's working fine with this piece of code, but how can I do it that it **increments Uses** everytime? I hope you understand my problem.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user (`deviceid`, `uses`) VALUES ('$DeviceID', $Uses)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `uses` = '$Uses'";
```

Comment: $uses++ or $uses + 1

Comment: @doug That won't work in SQL.

Comment: I hope for  your sake that all values here are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to let MySQL manage the change to the field like this code here:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user (`deviceid`, `uses`) VALUES ('$DeviceID', 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `uses` = `uses` + 1";
```

Note: I removed `$Uses` from the statement, it doesn't make any sense. If you're inserting for the first time it should be 1. If it exists it will be set by MySQL.

Comment: and I had to change the quotes from ` to ' in the 'uses + 1' but I think my edit got reject, otherwise I get this error:  Unknown column 'uses+1' in 'field list'

Comment: It should be: \`uses\` = \`uses\` + 1

Comment: Thank you, now it works, but is there a way to avoid that the table id's (not the DeviceID's) are like this? 1, 13, 20, 33. So every time I update something it increments the auto_increment id

Comment: I think the only way to prevent your ids from incrementing would be to move the check logic into your application, i.e. `SELECT deviceid ..` first, check the result then `INSERT` or `UPDATE` as appropriate. (And remove the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` part)